# Python | Moving specific Files in User created Folder

Tags: python, shutil

I wrote a short script, where I want to moves all .CR2 (in the next step I want to choose between the first the first 2 or 6 files) Files to a Folder, which has been created before as raw_input.

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil
import itertools

proname = raw_input("Please Name the Productfolder: ")

path = "/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/"

os.mkdir(proname)
os.chdir(proname)
os.makedirs('_final')
os.makedirs('_images')
os.makedirs('_psd')

sourcepath = '/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/03.01/'
sourcefiles = os.listdir(sourcepath)
destinationpath = '/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/03.01/%proname/_images/'
for file in sourcefiles:
    if file.endswith('.CR2'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpath,file))
```

At the moment, the script creates the user specific Folder (proname) and generates the subfolder _images, _final & _psd inside of it.

My Problem is that it doesn't moves the files from the top folder in the user created folder.

The Perfect Result would be if

1. I can choose a Productfolder Name
2. It creates inside of the Folder the subfolder _images, _final & _psd
3. I can choose if I want the first 2-6 .CR2 Files inside of the Subfolder _images of the created Productfolder
4. The Script is running till there are no .CR2 Files left

Any help or hints are welcome (:

Thx in advance

Comment: Do you want first two or first six .CR2 files to be moved to _images folder ?

Comment: it the best case I want to be able to choose between two or six. But for the first steps 2 would be fine. So I can work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html), `dst` is a directory, not a file.

> shutil.move(src, dst) Recursively move a file or directory (src) to
>   another location (dst). If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.

```
# Before:
shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpath,file))

# After:
shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), destinationpath))
```

will work.

Comment: I think my problem is more the line:

destinationpath = '/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/03.01/%proname/_images/'
for file in sourcefiles:

I think the %proname doesn't work as I want it to be the created folder, which can be one time xxx-xxx_111222-333 and another time anything else

Comment: How do you put %proname into destinationpath string? Doesn't connecting string work? Like '/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/03.01/'+'xxx-xxx'+/_images/'.

Comment: solved it now with:

destinationpath = os.path.join('/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/03.01/', proname, '_images')

Answer (score 0):

The following change solved the problem, with moving .CR2 Files in the specific proname Folder:

```
destinationpath = os.path.join('/Volumes/01_Produktfotos/_2020-01-JANUAR/03.01/', proname, '_images')
```

Now I'm in the next step, where not all .CR2 files should be moved. Just the first 2 or 6 files.